# Weired COMMAND in container for ASP.NET Core applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, windows, docker

I developed a ASP.NET Core service in Visual Studio 2019 with "Docker Support" (Linux Container).

The solution contains three projects, with one service and two librarys.

Starting and debugging works as expected. I can see "tail -f /dev/null" in the COMMAND column of

```
docker container ps
```

, what make sense while debugging in my opinion.

I added UseKestrel() to the webhost configuration, suggested somewhere...

If I try to build the Dockerfile via context menu inside Visual Studio, a "COPY failed" error appears. After reading the last days about docker and .NET Core, I can fix this by using PowerShell and

```
docker build -f .\fooWebService\Dockerfile -t foowebservice --target base --label "com.microsoft.created_by_visual_studio_2019" .
```

The Dockerfile looks like (generated from creating project):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["fooWebService/fooWebService.csproj", "fooWebService/"]
COPY ["IfooInterface/fooInterface.csproj", "IfooInterface/"]
COPY ["fooService/fooService.csproj", "fooService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "fooWebService/fooWebService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/fooWebService"
RUN dotnet build "fooWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "fooWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "fooWebService.dll"]
```

This will end up in the foowebservice:latest image.

If I try to run this image (after fiddeling with certificates, Kestrel, parameter, options, aaaaarg), it won't start. The container stops immediately.

```
docker run -d -p 63173:80 -p 44304:443 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:443;http://+:80" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44304 Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.dotnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx -e Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=crypticpassword -v $env:USERPROFILE/.aspnet/https/:/root/.dotnet/https foowebservice
```

The thing is, now in the COMMAND column appears "bash"! What about the ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile? Complete ignored?

In a 'I-dont-remember-anymore'-combination, I can go interactive into the container and see that the /app-directory is available, but empty.
I don't really know, if there must be something inside? The line

```
:
WORKDIR /app
:
```

suggest that behavior.

The whole bunch of steps I do with the simplest project template for ASP.NET Core webservice, and this one shows "dotnet TestWebApp.dll" in COMMAND as expected?!?

```
PM> docker ps -a
aa2f9a8b0512        test                       "dotnet test.dll"     3 seconds ago        Up 1 second                     0.0.0.0:63173->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:44304->443/tcp   mystifying_mclean
d635bfac782b        mdtdbsinoswebservice:dev   "bash"                About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                                                   awesome_lamarr
1e14dc686250        mdtdbsinoswebservice:dev   "tail -f /dev/null"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                    0.0.0.0:63164->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:44395->443/tcp   sad_shockley
```

- aa2f9a8b0512 is the simple webapp, only "UseKestrel"-change
- d635bfac782b is from my docker build.... line
- 1e14dc686250 is the one from Visual Studio --> Run Docker

I can build, push, pull and run the simple one successfully on a linux server.

I have no clue for resolving this COMMAND behavior issue nor to understand, what happend on build my "More-Than-One-Project"-Solution and why it doesnt work as a standalone image/container besides IDE?

So my questions, at least, are:
What is the correct workflow for....

- creating a ASP.NET Core Solution in Visual Studio 2019 with dependency projects inside?
- modifying the DockerFile or using a docker-compose'ing for production like behavior?
- build a "standalone"-image and run the container successfully?

**New knowledge**

First, now I know that

```
... --target build ...
```

cannot result in a working image. The stages are not complete.

But I can't build an image in case of COPY failed any time.
In Dockerfile I try relative paths, absolute paths, form solution directory, from project directory, same in combination of the

```
docker build -f ...
```

syntax, but nothing works!
I'm not able to do a simple COPY ["thisfile",""] without a

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder849213770/usless.file: no such file or directory
```

Error.
The tipp from [.net core docker is working via VS2019, but image build is getting error and not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475041/net-core-docker-is-working-via-vs2019-but-image-build-is-getting-error-and-not) doesn't solve my problem.

The most confusing thing is, that the simple test project works.

**...one step further**

It was the last parameter of

```
docker build -f ".\fooWebService\Dockerfile" -t foowebservice:dev --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=fooWebService" "."
```

, that change the behavior of Build-/Source-/Contextpath problems.

But now I can't get external references within the

```
dotnet build
```

process.
The build fails with

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "MyUsefulLibrary". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, y
>   ou may get compilation errors. [/src/fooService/fooService.csproj]

Q: Don't know at the time, where to put these libraries while building in image...?

I try also to use a local NuGet-repository and build packages from my libraries, but the build process searchs the packages in 'nuget.org'... !
Q: No idea where I can add these packages into build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Hello everybody,

For anyone who has the same problems docking an ASP.NET solution with projects that are not in the same directory, I think there is a workaround.

Since there is no automatism, some steps have to be solved manually.

First you have to add '*Container Orchestration Support*'.

After that you got (Example solution directory structure):

```
Somewhere
+- Library1
|  +- Library1 Project
|     +- Library1.csproj
+- Library2
|  +- Library2 Project
|     +- Library2.csproj
+- Main
|  +- Main Project
|  |  +- Main.csproj
|  |  +- Dockerfile
|  +- docker-compose.yml
|  +- .dockerignore
```

In the resulting *docker-compose.yml* change the **context** path to .. and the path to the Dockerfile.

```
context: .
dockerfile: Main Project/Dockerfile
```

to

```
context: ..
dockerfile: Main/Main Project/Dockerfile
```

This moves the root directory from the project directory to your development directory 'Somewhere'.

In order for the contents of the .dockerignore file to work, you have to deposit a copy in the directory, the context points now.

```
Somewhere
+- Library1
|  :
+- Library2
|  :
+- Main
|  :
+- .dockerignore
```

Now the paths in the Dockerfile have to be adjusted.

For each COPY, the path must be entered for pointing into the project directory in the **src** part.
The relative information **../** can be removed.

Before build, the WORKDIR must now be extended by the working directory.

Example Dockerfile (VS generated):

```
:
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Main Project/Main.csproj", "Main Project/"]
COPY ["../Library1/Library1 Project/Library1.csproj", "../Library1/Library1 Project/"]
COPY ["../Library2/Library2 Project/Library2.csproj", "../Library2/Library2 Project/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Main Project/Main.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Main Project"
RUN dotnet build "Main.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Main.csproj" -c Release -o /app
:
```

...change to:

```
:
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Main/Main Project/Main.csproj", "Main/Main Project/"]
COPY ["Library1/Library1 Project/Library1.csproj", "Library1/Library1 Project/"]
COPY ["Library2/Library2 Project/Library2.csproj", "Library2/Library2 Project/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Main/Main Project/Main.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Main/Main Project"
RUN dotnet build "Main.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Main.csproj" -c Release -o /app
:
```

If you create the solution now, the process runs smoothly and successfully!

Hope someone finds these hints useful.